# Where does "Accel World: Infinite burst" fit into the story?

Tags: accel-world

I've watched the Accel World anime and have gotten through a couple of the light novels but am not up to date.

Does the new movie follow after the anime? Or should I read the light novels before watching the movie?

Comment: from my understanding *Accel World: Infinite Burst* is an original story like how *Sword Art Online: Ordinal Scale* is original though it could be like Ordinal Scale in which it is set where the anime currently finished

Answer (score -1):

the anime covers the first 4 light novels, the movie takes place after light novel 21

Comment: Formatting, lack of evidence and it being a generally poor answer aside, it does answer the question quite succinctly.